# Se repite el último objeto al traer las filas de la BBDD en Java

Tags: java, jtable

Estoy intentando traer a una JTabel la información de la base de datos de todas las filas, la cuestión es que para ello tengo declarados un Array dentro de una función donde recibo los resulsets. He creado dentro del while un objeto donde almaceno  esos datos, yo creo que el problema está a la hora de crear dichos objetos para meter las diferentes filas en cada objeto, porque al hacer un sout, si me muestra la información de todas las filas, pero cuando muestro el array estan el numero de filas pero se repite en todas la informacion de la ultima fila.

```
private Object[][] obtenerMatrizDatos(ArrayList<String> titulosList) {
        
            ArrayList<datosTabla> lista = new ArrayList<datosTabla>();
        // String query = "SELECT  usuarios.nombre,usuarios.apellido FROM usuarios  INNER JOIN login ON usuarios.id_user=login.id WHERE  login.correo = '" + co + "'";
        String query = "SELECT  * FROM calculos";

        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlAPG + baseDatos, userAPG, password);

            stmt = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {

                datosTabla datos1 = new datosTabla();

                datos1.setCodi(rs.getInt("codigo"));
                datos1.setNombreYapellido(traerNomyApe(RegistroBBDD.co));
                String d = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("dia"));
                datos1.setDia1(d);
                datos1.setMes1(rs.getString("mes"));
                String y = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("year"));
                datos1.setAño1(y);
                datos1.setIngresos(rs.getInt("ingresos_totales"));
                datos1.setGastos(rs.getInt("gastos_totales"));
                datos1.setNeto(rs.getInt("saldo_neto"));
                datos1.setRiesgo(rs.getInt("calculo_riesgo"));
                datos1.setNetoDiario(rs.getInt("gasto_diario"));
                lista.add(datos1);

                

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
           System.out.println(lista.size());
        /**
         * se crea la matriz donde las filas son dinamicas pues corresponde a
         * todos los usuarios, mientras que las columnas son estaticas
         * correspondiendo a las columnas definidas por defecto
         */
        String informacion[][] = new String[lista.size()][titulosList.size()];

        for (int x = 0; x < informacion.length; x++) {

           

            informacion[x][0] = lista.get(x).getCodi() + "";
            informacion[x][1] = lista.get(x).getNombreYapellido() + "";
            informacion[x][2] = lista.get(x).getDia1() + "";
            informacion[x][3] = lista.get(x).getMes1() + "";
            informacion[x][4] = lista.get(x).getAño1() + "";
            informacion[x][5] = lista.get(x).getIngresos() + "";
            informacion[x][6] = lista.get(x).getGastos() + "";
            informacion[x][7] = lista.get(x).getNeto() + "";
            informacion[x][8] = lista.get(x).getRiesgo() + "";
            informacion[x][9] = lista.get(x).getNetoDiario() + "";
            informacion[x][Utilidades.PERFIL] = "PERFIL";
            informacion[x][Utilidades.EVENTO] = "EVENTO";
        }

        return informacion;
```

Las 4 filas de la tabla son las siguientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que obtengo son las 4 filas que tiene la base de datos pero me repite 4 veces la ultima insertada como muestra la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias y disculpen los muchos fallos que tenga, acabo de empezar con Java.

un saludo.

Yo creo que el problema lo tengo dentro del while donde capturo los datos con el resulset, la siguiente imagen es de un system.out.print del array dentro del while donde comos se ve claramente que los objetos no se guardan correctamente y se van sumando pero repetidamente. no se como solucionarlo y no encuentro informacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdona, en llegar a casa lo cambio, pensé que sería práctico, mil disculpas

Comment: Como dijo el primer comentario, aquí se publica todo el código en texto. En caso de ser necesario para demostrar algo, se adjunta la imagen.

Comment: Vuelvo a pedir disculpas es mi primera vez, voy a editar la pregunta en breves.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Publicar el codigo esta bien, pero publicaste mil lineas de codigo, y es dificil identificar donde esta tu problema. Tambien, usa el boton [edit] sobre la pregunta para editarla. deberias mostrar con que objeto cargas esa tabla, y como llenas ese objeto.. con eso, alcanzaria para empezar...

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme con la edicion

Comment: Ok.. falta donde cargas la tabla.. el codigo parece estar correcto...

Comment: Haciendo un debug, nada más salir del while, add(datos1) solo me guarda la última fila, es como si los objetos no se añadiesen, si no se sobre escriben, dejando los cuatros objetos con la misma informacion. Desde ese punto es donde está el error, Revisa el codigo, lo he modificado para ver todos los pasos. Gracias

Comment: UP! alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, después de varios días.
La solución era quitar el static de la clase datosTabla

Comment: Qué extraña solución... De todas maneras, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.